# Click on last row of an HTML table with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click on the last row of a table using python and selenium. I have highlighted what I am trying to click in the HTML code image.

[image]

```
lastRow =  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("td.phone-leftinline yui-dt6-col-Type yui-dt-col-Type yui-dt-first:last-of-type"))
lastRow.click()
```

This codes keeps throwing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daniel/Python/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    lastRow =  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("td.phone-leftinline yui-dt6-col-Type yui-dt-col-Type yui-dt-first:last-of-type"))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
lastRow =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH("(//table[1]/tbody/tr)[last()]"));
```

Comment: What about `lastRow =  driver.find_element(By.XPATH("(//table[1]//tr)[last()]"));`. And if you wait a couple of secs before interacting with the element? Maybe it did not load when you try to interact with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax errors with both expressions you trying to use.
I can't validate it since you did not share a link to the page you working on, but try the following (fixed syntax of your trials):

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.phone-leftinline.yui-dt6-col-Type.yui-dt-col-Type.yui-dt-first:last-of-type").click()
```

or

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//table[1]/tbody/tr)[last()]").click()
```

Additionally you may need to wait for element clickability. `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit wait `element_to_be_clickable` is normally used for that.
**UPD**
Additionally to `last()` XPath supports indexing elements so that you can select first, second, n-th element, as following:
This will select the first element

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//table[1]/tbody/tr)[1]").click()
```

This will select the second

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//table[1]/tbody/tr)[2]").click()
```

etc.
Pay attention: In XPath indexation  starts with 1, not with 0 as in most other places.

Comment: Your code worked. How would I go about selecting the first row with XPATH?

Comment: Well, this is a new question, but I added the answer here.